# HghCharts drilldown module: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lang' of undefined

Tags: javascript, highcharts, typeerror

On HighCharts drilldown module, getting the following error.

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lang' of undefined"

[image]

Here is the drilldown js, https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js

Comment: We're going to need to see your configuration.  Including the library's code isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Having this error with version 5.0.0, instead of that I have added previous version 4.2.7 from https://cdnjs.com/libraries/highcharts/4.2.7

That's all; Issue Resolved!!